# Not able to connect to my server

Tags: server, router

I have a small local network, with the following devices: a router , a Dell laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS as my server, and another HP laptop to test access.

My IP addresses look like this:

```
router: 192.168.0.1
server: 192.168.0.101 
laptop: 192.168.0.100
```

I have successfully setup LAMP and have one small page `(/var/www/html/index.html)` with one picture.  I can't access this from my HP laptop by entering 192.168.0.101 into Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: @MIRMIX: there's no need to add so much formatting. In particular, you've used a quote block for something that is not a quote. The quote device is not a general highlighter. Thanks!

Comment: Ankit, please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access your server you have to make it publicly so I will describe the steps required to do it:

1. Login to your router, search for `Port Forwarding` section and forward the port 80(HTTP Port) to 192.168.0.101(Your Web Server). You can find a guide for `Port Forwarding` after selecting your router model here : https://portforward.com/router.htm
2. Access your webserver by your external Ip. http://yourexternalip
3. (Optional) If you have dynamic Ip, you can set a Dynamic DNS to create a domain name that will always point to your webserver even your Ip will change after a router reboot or something like that. You can read this guide for setting up a DDNS: https://www.howtogeek.com/66438/how-to-easily-access-your-home-network-from-anywhere-with-ddns/

Comment: How to get my external ip ?

Comment: i forwarded port 80 using the virtual servers option. Also I tried to access my server PC using external ip but still it is not able to connect.

Comment: when i am trying to connect in my browser it say, connection timed out. But I am able to ping it from my laptop. Also I tried by installing vsftpd and it is able to open the ftp page but in http its not showing any result.